# Firefox stays in browser full screen after minimizing the browser that had a full screen video open

Tags: firefox, video, fullscreen, about-config

**Behavior on my Firefox:**

1. Go to youtube or any video website
2. Click the full screen button on a video
3. Minimize Firefox
4. When maximizing Firefox, the previously full screen video is no longer full screen, and Firefox is stuck in browser full screen mode (which is fixed by pressing F11)

The issue doesn't appear in safe mode, however disabling all my extensions and custom CSS hasn't fixed the issue so that is unclear. I've narrowed down a config that does show some progress.

Enabling `full-screen-api.ignore-widgets` fixes the issue in that when the video goes full screen, and the browser is minimized, when returning to the page the video is now no longer full screen and the browser didn't go into browser full screen mode which is the expected behavior.

The reason this isn't a complete fix is when the video is in full screen mode using that config, the top window title bar (on firefox) is visible during video full screen mode.

**Question:** Does anyone have any insight in a config or reason that minimized firefox may not be undoing browser full screen mode when maximizing the browser?

> Firefox version: 107.0 (64-bit) for Ubuntu